# How to get around the ' (quote) problem when saving text using SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql

I've a textbox that I save to a SQL Database using ASP.NET C#.

The problem is using quotes, for instance with words like he's and it's.  When you save it, I get an SQL error.

From experience to get around the issue, I use to use replace command to find all occurances of quotes and replace them with another character.  Then if I was to read the database and the text that was previously saved, I'd replace again.

Is there a better of doing this? Or do you still have to use this 'old' way.

Comment: Did you find a site/example showing something like `"SELECT * FROM x WHERE y='" + something + "'"`?  We should collectively hunt them down..

Comment: Please note what folk are saying about parameterised queries: SQL injection is a serious issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use parametrized queries.

Using replace is dangerous and can lead to unintentional SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Seriously, use parameters. It's a whole lot easier than trying to deal with every corner case.

Comment: the injection risk is really the issue - USE PARAMETERS

Comment: Thanks for the tip;  Haven't programmed in a long time, this is all coming back to me bit by bit. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Always use parameterized queries.  Never concatenate strings together (with un-sanitised input information) to create SQL on the fly.  You run the risk of being vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks.

Read the following guide carefully:

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx

And when you understand the following comic strip, you are ready to code:

http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers point out, the **correct** answer here is to use **parameterized queries**.

However, this is sometimes not possible. In these cases, you're better off doubling the quotes:

```
String str = "he's";
str = str.Replace("'", "''");
```

Comment: Note: The correct way of escaping strings in SQL varies from one database system to another. I know that the above method works for SQL Server and MS Access. For any other database it may be different, and the above method should not be used without verifying it for the specific database. It should for example *not* be used for MySQL. (Not my downvote, btw)

Comment: I don't think this is enough to be risk-free from injection.  There are other characters that can be used to break out of commands (for example, the backspace character). (Not my downvote either)

Comment: I completely agree that this method should not be used - which is why I concurred that the **correct** answer is parameterized queries. The OP was asking for a simple improvement on his replacement methods though, so I added the alternative to give a direct answer to their question.

Comment: Not mine either, but if there's no way of using parameterized queries in asp.net, it's the developer's own doing (creating a wrapper or something).  That wrapper should be removed and re-written.  Parameterized queries are always available

Comment: @Kieren, fair point - when I said it's sometimes not possible, I was thinking of SPs, but of course, parameterized queries != stored procedures, so yeah, they are _(should be)_ always available.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to get around this issue:

1. Use a parameterised query, e.g. in http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx - this will also help avoid basic SQL injection if you're worried about that
2. Create 2 new functions, one to double up every apostrophe, so that it's saved into the database correctly, and another to remove extra apostrophes when retrieving data from the database.

I would recommend the first method as it's a lot cleaner (and safer) in my opinion.  If you're using C# for your ASP.NET you can do things like in my below example:

```
string clientName = "Test client";
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Client WHERE UPPER(ClientName) = UPPER(@ClientName)", connection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientName", clientName);
```